# How to conditionally turn off a JS plugin in Foundation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

Using jQuery, I am trying to conditionally load the [Magellan sticky nav plugin of the Foundation framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/magellan.html) depending on screensize:

window width > 640px ==> Load Magellan with specified options

window width < 640px ==> Turn Magellan off

The resizing event seems to fire, but the plugin does not seem to have an `off` option.

I got the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* foundation magellan scroller*/

    function checkWidth() {

        var $windowSize = $(window).width();

        if ( $windowSize > 640 ) {

            $(document).foundation({

                "magellan-expedition": {
                  active_class: 'active', // specify the class used for active sections
                  threshold: 0, // how many pixels until the magellan bar sticks, 0 = auto
                  destination_threshold: 50, // pixels from the top of destination for it to be considered active
                  throttle_delay: 50, // calSculation throttling to increase framerate
                  fixed_top: 75, // top distance in pixels assigend to the fixed element on scroll
                  offset_by_height: true // whether to offset the destination by the expedition height. Usually you want this to be true, unless your expedition is on the side.
                }

            });

        } else {

            $(document).foundation('magellan', 'off');

        }
    }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();

    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);

});
```

Comment: The documentation ```magellan``` doesn't seem to have an ```off``` option. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html Seems to be some info here too around the issue https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2956

Comment: You're right. There seems to be an issue with the `off` option and the resize event seems to fire correctly. Will rephrase the question.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but shouldn't the resize trigger be outside of the document ready function?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the html markup but you can remove or turn off the magellan sticky by removing the data attribute

if you html looks like this

inside you else statement remove att

```
 else {

          $(".navi-f").removeAttr("data-magellan-expedition");

    }
```

this way its like turning off the plugin